# Error Deploying to Azure in Build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm working on creating a build pipeline that to compile an ApiWebApp and deploy it to Azure from Visual Studio Online. My build flow is:

- Visual Studio Build
- Publish Build Artifacts
- Azure Web App Deployments

My questions are:

- Is it reasonable to deploy an API App from Visual Studio Online to Azure? 
  Hoping the answer to this is yes.
- Do I have the right steps in my pipeline?
- In the Azure Web App Deployments step, what should I enter for the 'Web Deploy Package' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is reasonable, and you have the right build steps in your build definition.

You need to have a check on this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/06/12/deploying-an-azure-web-site-using-the-new-build-system-in-visual-studio-online.aspx), it describes the details on how to deploy an Azure Web Site using the new build system in Visual Studio Online.

Here are some important steps I would like to highlight from there:

1. Firstly, you need to register your Azure subscription in TFS.
2. Secondly, in the Visual Studio Build step, pass the following argument to MSBuild: **/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"** These specific settings will create a web deploy package and put it in the staging directory of the build definition.
3. Thirdly, in the Azure Web App Deployment step, set **Web Deploy Package** $(build.stagingDirectory)\projectname.zip.

Comment: That did it. Can I assume the same procedure works for Mobile App backends?

Comment: Just wondering: The arguments in #2 don't seem to work properly with ASP.NET5 project. I can't get a Web Deploy Package (.zip) generated. Any idea or clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is reasonable.

Here are the steps:

Step 1: Create a team project

Step 2: Check in a project to source control

Step 3: Connect the project to Azure (In azure portal)

Step 4: Trigger a rebuild and redeploy your project

Here is a complete steps on how you can do it:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

In the package text box you can enter:
($build.stagingDirectory)YourProjectName.zip

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Was able to follow your steps, but hit another issue. Any thoughts?

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.0.17.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.targets.